# distinct count on hive does not match cardinality count on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, hive, hiveql, querydsl, elasticsearch-hadoop

I have loaded data into my `elasticsearch` cluster from hive using the `elasticsearch-hadoop` plugin from `elastic`.

I need to fetch a count of unique account numbers. I have the following queries written in both `hql` and `queryDSL`, *BUT* they are returning different counts.

Hive Query:

```
select count(distinct account) from <tableName> where capacity="550";

// Returns --> 71132
```

Similarly, in Elasticsearch the query looks like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
              {"match": { "capacity": "550"}}
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
    "unique_account": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "account"
      }
    }
  }
}

// Returns --> 71607
```

Am I doing something wrong? What can I do to match the two queries?

`Note:` There are exactly the same number of records in hive and elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "the first **approximate** aggregation provided by Elasticsearch is
> the cardinality metric
> ...
> As mentioned at the top of this chapter, the cardinality metric is an
> **approximate** algorithm. It is based on the HyperLogLog++ (HLL)
> algorithm."
>
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

#### For the OP

precision_threshold

> "precision_threshold accepts a number from 0–40,000. Larger values are
> treated as equivalent to 40,000.
> ...
> Although not guaranteed by the
> algorithm, if a cardinality is under the threshold, it is almost
> always 100% accurate. Cardinalities above this will begin to trade
> accuracy for memory savings, and a little error will creep into the
> metric."
>
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html

You might also want to take a look at ["Support for precise cardinality aggregation #15876"](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15876)

#### For the OP, 2

> "I have tried several numbers..."

You have **71,132** distinct values while the precision threshold limit is **40,000**, therefore  the cardinality is **over** the threshold, which means accuracy is traded for memory saving.
This is how the chosen implementation  (based on HyperLogLog++ algorithm) works.

Comment: I tried adding a `"precision_threshold" : 100` and it still shows some numbers that are way off. There must be an equivalent way to do it just like in hive.

Comment: `"precision_threshold" : 100` does not mean 100% accuracy. See updated answer.

Comment: I have tried several numbers between `0` and `40000` and the result is still not accurate. I am a little confused here. Why can't `elasticsearch` count and give me an accurate number like `hive`? I don't think I am expecting out of the world functionality here  :(

Answer (score 0):

Cardinality does not ensure accurate count even with 40000 precision_threshold. There is another way to get accurate distinct count of a field.

This article on "[Accurate Distinct Count and Values from Elasticsearch](https://pratik-patil.medium.com/accurate-distinct-count-and-values-from-elasticsearch-dadce51ad4a7)" explains in detail the solution as well as it's accuracy over Cardinality.